# Android: Adding a linearLayout in a LinearLayout from a separate xml file

Tags: android, layout, horizontalscrollview

I got a relative layout which contains another relative layout which I used to replace the "title", a linearLayout which I will use later as a "control panel", and a horizontalScrollView, where the horizontalScrollView contains a LinearLayout(let's name this linear layout - "hsc".

I also have another xml layout file named "entries" that contains an imageView.

My question is, how do i attach "entries" inside "hsc"? Or how to I populate "hsc" with multiple "entries"?

My main layout's structure looks something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <relativeLayout1>
    <linearLayout>
    <horizontalScrollView1>
        <hsc>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to populate "entries" dynamically?

Comment: yes.. and I want to add entries as an array. something that works like listViewAdapter..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). First get the hsc in code somehow like this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hsc_id);
```

Then you make new entrie

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View entrie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries,
            null, false);
```

and put one into another

```
layout.addView(entrie);
```

you can add multiple views by repeating child view creation process.

Comment: Ok, i managed to add the "entries" layout inside the linearLayout(hsc) which is inside the horizontalScrollView

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hsc);
    View v = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.entries, null);
    ll.addView(v);

Only now, i need to add multiple "entries" inside it. But doesn't work. Can someone teach me how to add "entries" as an array?

Comment: @KenndeLeon for(View v: Views){ //Views is an Iterable<View> class - an array or list implementation
  ll.addView(v);
  }

Comment: I used View entrie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries,null, false); But when i call layout.addView(entrie) twice, it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

If your are going to populate the view, you may want to use a ListView (FragmentList or ListActivity).

In which case you use the tag

```
<RelativeLayout>
<relativeLayout1>
<linearLayout>
<horizontalScrollView1>    
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

And then load the list with an Adapter.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/

Your question seem to imply that you some-how need to traverse the xml tree, you don't, you just use android:id to find the resource from the code side.

Comment: or in any case, can i set list to scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

create a linear layout dynamically and add some view in that.....

```
             LinearLayout layoutContainer=new LinearLayout(your_activity.this);  //create a linear layout dynamically

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            layoutContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);//apply attributes to your linear layout

            View viewOther = LayoutInflater.from(your_activity.this)
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_to_add, layoutContainer);//add some view to your linear_layout.
```

hope it helps....!